# How to arbitrarily separate navigation items using simple-navigation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, navigation

I can't figure out how to configure my navigation so that I can call out different parts in different places in my layout, other than to use the 'level' system provided.

Really my navigation isn't two 'levels' - I just want some of it rendered in one div and some rendered in another.

I could hack my application's navigation such that one part is nested within another and use `render_navigation :level => 2`, but if there's a more sensible way to go I'd much prefer it!

Ideally I'd like to be doing something like:
(haml)

```
#foo= render_navigation :part => "main"
#bar= render_navigation :part => "extra"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you can specify different navigation sections in separate config files and call them with `:context => "foobar"`

https://github.com/codeplant/simple-navigation/wiki/faq#q10